# all the responsive breakpoints for every devices?

Tags: css

confuse in this break points either for mac or for large screen
I have try this but in some break points slider will be invisible and again after that it was visible
confuse in this break points either for mac or for large screen
I have try this but in some break points slider will be invisible and again after that it was visible

```
/*Large Desktop for mac*/
@media(min-width: 1600px) and (max-width:2000px){
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
    height:325px !important;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport ul.slider-home li{
    height: 325px !important;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport .slider-image{
    height: 100% !important;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
}

/*Large Desktop*/
@media(max-width:1024px){

.entry-content .wrapper:after, .entry-content .wrapper:before{
    display: none;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
    height:489px !important;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport ul.slider-home li{
    height: 489px !important;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport .slider-image{
    background-size: 100%;
}

}


/*Potrait tablet to Landscape and Desktop*/
@media(min-width:768px ) and (max-width: 980px){

.wrapper{
    width: 750px;
}

.site-branding {
    width: 260px;
}

.site-branding img{
    width: 100%;
}

.site-header .main-navigation ul li a {
    padding: 16px 14px 17px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.site-header .main-navigation ul li:first-child a::before{
    left: -54px;
    width: 66px;
}

.topic-heading .part2 .reflected{
    font-size: 45px;
}

.topic-heading .part2 .reflected:before, 
.topic-heading .part2 .reflected:after{
    bottom: -32px;
}

.topic-heading .part1 .blue{
    font-size: 36px;
    width: 485px;
}

.services-content .services{
    width: 230px;
}

.services-content .services img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 5px;
}

.services-content .services .post-title {
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.site-footer .info-side{
    width: 460px;
}

.site-footer .find-us .pts{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.site-footer .find-us .find-us-BB, .site-footer .find-us .find-us-fb{
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.site-footer .menu-main-menu-container ul li{
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.site-footer .menu-main-menu-container ul li:last-child{
    padding-right: 0;
}



/*-------About Us----------*/
.entry-content .wrapper .primary{
    width: 365px;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .widget-area{
    width: 335px;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .widget-area img{
    width: 100%;
}

/*--------------clients-------------*/
.entry-content .wrapper .left, .entry-content .wrapper .right{
    width: 47%;
}

/*-------------- Videos-------------------*/

.videos-content .services{
    width: 366px;
}

.videos-content .services > iframe.youtube-player{
    width: 100%;
    height: 295px;
}


/*--------Contact Us----------------*/
.entry-content .wrapper .wpcf7-form input[type="text"], 
.entry-content .wrapper .wpcf7-form input[type="email"], 
.entry-content .wrapper .wpcf7-form input[type="tel"], 
.entry-content .wrapper .wpcf7-form textarea{
    width: 100%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
    height:366px !important;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport ul.slider-home li{
    height: 366px !important;
}


}


/*Landscape Phones to Potrait tablet*/
@media(max-width: 767px){

.wrapper{
    width:96%;
    padding: 0 2%;
}

.site-header .main-navigation{
    display: none;
}

.slicknav_menu {
    display: block;
}

.site-header .site-branding {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.site-header .call-us {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
}

.topic-heading .part1 .blue{
    width: 520px;
}


.topic-heading .part2 .reflected:before, 
.topic-heading .part2 .reflected:after{
    display: none;
}

.services-content .services{
    width: 225px;
}

.site-footer .find-us {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.site-footer .find-us .pts, .site-footer .find-us .find-us-BB, 
.site-footer .find-us .find-us-fb{
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right:32px;
}

.site-footer .find-us .pts, .site-footer .find-us .find-us-BB{
    margin-left: 0;
}
.site-footer .find-us .find-us-fb{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.site-footer .info-side {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
}


/*----------About Us---------*/

.entry-content .wrapper .primary{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .widget-area{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.entry-content .wrapper .widget-area img{
    width: 100%;
}


/*--------Clients--------------*/

.entry-content .wrapper .left, .entry-content .wrapper .right{
    width: 45%;
}

/*-------------- Videos-------------------*/

.videos-content .services{
    width: 359px;
}

.videos-content .services > iframe.youtube-player{
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px;
}


/*-------Contact Us-------------*/
.entry-content .wrapper .wpcf7-form input[type="text"], 
.entry-content .wrapper .wpcf7-form input[type="email"], 
.entry-content .wrapper .wpcf7-form input[type="tel"], 
.entry-content .wrapper .wpcf7-form textarea{
    width: 100%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
    height:366px !important;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport ul.slider-home li{
    height: 366px !important;
}


}



/*Landscape Phones to Potrait tablet and Down*/
@media(max-width: 640px){


.services-content{
    margin-left: -19px;
}

.services-content .services {
    width: 29.3%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.services-content .services img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .left, .entry-content .wrapper .right{
    width: 42%;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .left .sub-title:before, 
.entry-content .wrapper .right .sub-title:before{
    width: 265px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
    height:305px !important;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport ul.slider-home li{
    height: 305px !important;
}

/*-------------- Videos-------------------*/

.videos-content .services{
    width: 298px;
}

.videos-content .services > iframe.youtube-player{
    width: 100%;
    height: 240px;
}

}

@media(max-width: 580px){

.entry-content .wrapper .left .sub-title:before, 
.entry-content .wrapper .right .sub-title:before{
    width: 235px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
    height:277px !important;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport ul.slider-home li{
    height: 277px !important;
}

/*-------------- Videos-------------------*/

.videos-content .services{
    width: 269px;
}

.videos-content .services > iframe.youtube-player{
    width: 100%;
    height: 217px;
}

}


/*Landscape phones and Down*/
@media(max-width: 480px){

.bx-controls-direction {
    display: none;
}

.topic-heading .part1 .blue{
    width: 88%;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.topic-heading .part2 .reflected{
    font-size: 50px;
}

.services-content .services {
    width: 44.2%;
    margin-left: 4%;
}

.site-footer .menu-main-menu-container ul li a{
    font-size: 17px;
}

.site-footer .menu-main-menu-container ul li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .left .sub-title:before, 
.entry-content .wrapper .right .sub-title:before{
    width: 200px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
    height:229px !important;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport ul.slider-home li{
    height: 229px !important;
}

/*-------------- Videos-------------------*/

.videos-content .services{
    width:100%;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.videos-content .services > iframe.youtube-player{
    width: 100%;
    height: 370px;
}

}



/*Landscape Phones*/
@media(max-width: 320px){


.site-header .site-branding{
    width: 95%;
}

.site-header .site-branding img{
    width: 100%;
}

.site-header .call-us{
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.site-header .call-us span.blue {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
}


.topic-heading .part1 .blue{
    font-size: 22px;
}

.topic-heading .part2 .reflected {
    font-size: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
}

.services-content{
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.services-content .services{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.services-content .services img{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.site-footer .find-us .pts, .site-footer .find-us .find-us-BB, 
.site-footer .find-us .find-us-fb{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    padding-top: 0;

}

.site-footer .menu-main-menu-container ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .widget-area{
    width: 100%;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .primary .sub-title:before, 
.entry-content .wrapper .left .sub-title:before, 
.entry-content .wrapper .right .sub-title:before, 
.entry-content .wrapper .services-content .sub-title:before, 
.videos-content .sub-title:before{
    width: 100%;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .about-us-widget{
    padding: 25px 18px 30px;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .services-content .sub-title{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .left, .entry-content .wrapper .right{
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .right{
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-top: 20%;
}

.entry-content .wrapper .whatwe-text{
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
    height:152px !important;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport ul.slider-home li{
    height: 152px !important;
}

.videos-content .services > iframe.youtube-player{
    width: 100%;
    height: 247px;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add "all" to your media queries.
Like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: ???px)
```

And dont forget to add this to the head for your responsivity :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```